# Animated UIImageView which should recognize taps on it (at every location the UIImageView is at)

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, state, uigesturerecognizer

I'm making an iPhone App which involves balloons (UIImageViews) being spawned from the bottom of the screen and moving up to the top of the screen.

The aim is to have the UIImageViews set up so that a tap gesture on a balloon causes the balloons to be removed from the screen.

I have set up the GestureRecognizer and taps are being recognized.

The problem I am having is that the animation method I am using does not provide information about where the balloon is being drawn at a specific point in time, and treats it as already having reached the final point mentioned.

This causes the problem of the taps being recognized only at the top of the screen(which is the balloon's final destination).

I have pasted my code for animation here:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:options animations:^{ 
balloonImageView.center = p;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
if (finished) {
  balloonImageView.hidden= TRUE;
  balloonImageView.image=nil;
}
```

I keep track of where an image is by giving a unique tag to a UIImageView and checking if gesture.view.tag =  anyBalloonObject.tag and if it does I destroy the balloon.

My basic question is, is there another animation tool I can use? I understand that I can set a balloon's finish point to slightly higher than where it is on screen until it reaches the top but that seems like it is very taxing on memory. 
Do you have any recommendations? I looked through the Core Animation reference, and didn't find any methods that suited my needs.

In addition will the Multi-threading aspects of UIViewAnimation affect the accuracy of the tap system?

Thank You,

Vik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt animate game-objects (objects you interact with while they are moving) like that.
You should rather use a NSTimer to move the ballons.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

//Set up a timer to run the update-function
timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];

}


-(void) update {

for (int i = [balloonArray count] - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //Loop through an array containing all your balloons.


    UIImageView *aBalloon = [balloonArray objectAtIndex:i]; //Select balloon at the current loop index

    aBallon.center = CGPointMake(aBallon.center.x, aBalloon.center.y + 1); //Change the center of that balloon, in this case: make it go upwards.



}
}
```

Here is what you need to declare in .h:

```
NSTimer *timer;
NSMutableArray *ballonArray;
//You should use properties on these also..
```

You will have to create a spawn method which adds balloons to the screen AND to the array.
When you have done that, it's simple to implement the touch methods, You can just loop trough the balloons and check:

```
  //You need an excact copy of the loop from earlier around this if statement!
  If (CGRectContainsPoint(aBalloon.frame, touchlocation)) { //you can do your own tap detection here inthe if-statement
   //pop the balloon and remove it from the array!
    }
```

Hope that isnt too scary-looking, good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that wasn't scary looking at all.. I tried something similar to that but the part I didn't know how to code up was the touch gesture .. the CGRectContainsPoint method. 

Anyway .. it works the way I expect it to.. appreciate it.

Comment: you should explain why his approach is no valid and why your method is better